# Broken path to public files in parameterized route (React-Router-Dom v6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have public assets (styles, js) in my React appliacation.
If I load not parameterized route such as "/users" my public assets load path in networking is right (e.g "localhost:3000/assets/public/js/cat.js".
If I load parameterized route such as "/users/1" it adds unnecessary part to the link (e.g "localhost:3000/users/assets/public/js/cat.js").

Here is minimal reproducible example:

**index,js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**App.jsx**

```js
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cats from './Cats';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/users/:id" element={<Cats/>}/>      
      <Route path="/users" element={<Cats/>}/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Cats.jsx**

```
const Cats = () => {
  return (
    <div className="custom-div">
      <h1>CATS</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cats;
```

Also add this link to head of public/index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/new-styles.css">
```

And create following file at /public/assets/css/new-styles.css

```
.custom-div {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Then you should execute following commands in terminal

```
npm i react-router-dom
npm start
```

When you check localhost:3000/users you'll see Cats with Aqua background meanwhile at localhost:3000/users/1 you'll see Cats without any background.

Comment: What assets/content are you trying to load from your public directory? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? How are you running and serving the app locally?

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative path: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/new-styles.css">`. Or move your CSS file into your `src` directory with your app code and import your CSS file in your React code instead of via a `link` tag in the `index.html` file.

Comment: I added %PUBLIC_URL% to the path and it worked for me, thank you a lot!

Comment: Aye, welcome. Voting to close as "
Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.